# How to get the constructor method of a class?

Tags: class, constructor, metaprogramming, d

I have a class `A` that takes another class `B` as a template argument, and I need to get `B`'s constructor in order to do (somewhat pseudocode):

```
class A(B)
{
    import std.typecons : Tuple;
    import std.traits : Parameters;
    Tuple!(Parameters!B) _args;
    this(Parameters!B args)
    {
        _args = args;
    }
}
```

to store arguments for the constructor and later construct an object of class `B` with the arguments stored in `_args`.

This is pretty much the Command pattern.

Is there a way to get the constructor of `B` to get its `Parameters`?
Or is there a better way to achieve deferred object construction?

Comment: try B.__ctor to reference it.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the constructor's internal name is `__ctor`:

```
class C
{
    this(int a, string b) { }
}

import std.traits;

pragma(msg, Parameters!(C.__ctor));
```

This outputs:

```
(int, string)
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I hadn't included a constructor in one of the classes I passed to `A`, which made `B.__ctor` not exist in that case.

Comment: Note that you can use `__traits(getOverloads, C, "__ctor")` if there are multiple constructors. `MemberFunctionsTuple!(C, "__ctor")`, for whatever reason, returns an empty list. Not sure if that's intentional.